# Checking if date is overdue from text file

Tags: python, date, readlines, external-data-source

I have a text file that has users and then due dates. I would like to be able to read the due date which was initially input by the user and see if the date is overdue compared with the current date. Any help would be appreciated.

Text file:

> User: Tommy
>
> Gender: Male
>
> Date due: 2020-02-18

The code I have so far is:

```
import datetime
data = open("duedate.txt", "r")
    d = datetime.datetime.today()
    line = data.readlines(3)
    if line > d
        print("This date is overdue ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today()
with open("duedate.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith('Date due'): continue
        field, value = line.split(':')
        if field == 'Date due':
            if datetime.datetime.strptime(value.strip(), '%Y-%m-%d') < today:
                print("Overdue")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion... When i run the code... Its printing overdue even if the date is still valid. Thank you

Comment: Oh sorry, i inverted the logic, it should have been less than `<`. Editing.

Comment: @NoobDev88 could you check now?

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Thank you @Sayandip.... I should have realized that too but its perfect now thank you!